# DOM Element unique id

Tags: javascript, dom

I am recursing through elements in the DOM looking for the DOM element that matches the event.target element. What is the best way to find the event.target in the DOM besides just referring directly to event.target? Do DOM elements have some self-defined unique identifier that I can use to compare them?

Comment: No, there's no built-in ID. Javascript is object-oriented, the element itself is its own unique identifier.

Comment: Why do you need to recurse? `event.target` is the element, why do you need to search for it?

Comment: thats not how it works :) even objects have to have some way of identifying themsleves, whether it be memory location, or hash, or unique id, something unique has be available!

Comment: that's true, I probably don't need to recurse to look for the element if it's already in my hands, but I might have a good reason to do so, not sure yet

Comment: It's usually just the memory address. But that's not something you can access from Javascript, it's a hidden, internal detail. And it can change as a result of garbage collection. The only thing you can do is test whether two objects are the same or different, you can't get the unique identifier and save it.

Comment: ok so how to I check to see if two DOM nodes are equal?

Comment: I still think you're thinking about this all wrong. Can you show the code that needs to do this, there's almost certainly a better way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for equality you can just do this:

```
if (event.target === anotherElement) {
     // anotherElement is event.target
}
```

One reason you might want to recurse when you already have that element in hand, is to check if one element is a descendent of another element. For this you can use the [`.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) method:

```
if (containerElement.contains(event.target)) {
     // event.target is a descendent of containerElement
}
```

Comment: thanks, do you know what the === operator is actually comparing in this case?

Comment: In javascript the `===` operator when comparing object, will return only true if the object is compared with it self. For example `{ a : 1 } === { a : 1 }` will be false because they are different objects but `var a = { b : 1 }; var b = a; a === b` will be true because variable b contains the same objects. If I were to write a javascript engine, each variable would be a pointer and I would compare the memory address. You might want to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 0):

DOM elements don't have unique ID's the only ID's they have, is the one you define in your html, for html elements. However, if you are looking for tracing your DOM elements, with some kind of key, I'd suggest to work with key - value list.

This way you will be able to trace your elements according to their given key in the list.

Please refer:

[Java script key - value article](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/javascript/create-key-value-pair-array-using-javascript)

[Java script objects tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/objects)